# Deleting images from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

I'm writing a code that selects images in a Listview and delete them from the server. Unfortunately I haven't been able to delete any image and no error during debug. Here is the code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID_BG" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_BGdelete">


<ItemTemplate>
                 <label><input id="checkbox1" name="BG_list" type="checkbox" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>'/>
                <img alt="" style="width:150px" src="/Members/images/BG/icons/<%# Eval("BG_fileName") %>"></label>      
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
                 <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                     <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                 </div>
                 <div style="">

<asp:Button class="btn btn-default" ID="DeleteBackground" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteBackground_click" />

                 </div>
             </LayoutTemplate>
 .....
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void DeleteBackground_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.ListView2.Items)
        {

            var checkBtn = (HtmlInputCheckBox)itemRow.FindControl("checkbox1");

            if (checkBtn.Checked)
            {
                string fileName = ("~/Members/images/BG/" + checkBtn.Value);
                if (fileName != null || fileName != string.Empty)
                {
                    if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
                    }

                }



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines

```
if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))) 
   System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
```

must be

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(fileName)))
   System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));
```

P.S.

It makes no sense to check `if (fileName != null || fileName != string.Empty)` because fileName is never null or empty.

Comment: thanks. I removed the if (fileName != null || fileName != string.Empty) as you suggested....We learn new things everyday...LOL

Answer (score 0):

certainly that the id="checkbox1" is rename by the renderer for not to have the same Id in item listView. Check the generated html.

Comment: Sure, the id will not be equal to "checkbox1" but to something like  "ListView2_ctrl0_checkbox1". However, *itemRow*.FindControl("checkbox1") should work fine.